# Magnetic field and magnetic domains

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I have a confusion regarding how magnetic field propagate in a medium (ferromagnets or air etc..). It is knows when a ferromagnet is exposed to an external magnetic field, the magnetic domain of the ferromagnet will be aligned with the external magnetic field. My question is this alignment of domain assure the propagation of the external magnetic field in the ferromagnet? The same question for the air. Do the magnetic field propagate in the air because the magnetic domains of the air are aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No alignment of magnetic domains in a medium is needed for a magnetic field to propagate in that medium. Magnetic fields can propagate through a vacuum despite the fact that there are no magnetic moments or domains at all in a vacuum, right?

Similarly, no dielectric moments are required for electric fields to propagate in a medium, and electric fields can travel perfectly well through a vacuum.

Comment: what does the alignment affect the magnetic field ?

Comment: @Tonylb1 - You mean how does the alignment of magnetic domains or magnetic moments affect the magnetic field? The alignment of magnetic domains or magnetic moments can enhance the strength of the magnetic field. Similarly, the alignment of electric dipole moments can enhance the strength of an electric field.